# If statment is not working in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have list of data coming from the database and my logic in jQuery is not working, I have 100 as total number of data. So what I want is if the list is less than 99 hide something else if the list is more than 100 then show something, this is what I placed under ajax success handler. I have tried loading 28 data and 100 but both time it hides 'something'. Can someone suggest why?

```
success: function(data){


if (data < 99) {             
    $('#something').show();
} else {
    $('#something').hide();
} }
```

When I first loaded my data was it was equal to 28 and the second time it was 129 and both the time brake point moved into hide();

Comment: can you show us codes above `if (data < 99) {` ?

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for `data.length` rather than `data`?

Comment: Is `data` an int or a string?

Comment: Maybe data.length < 99 if it is a list?

Comment: @howrad your right it was `data.length` thanks!

Comment: @User911 If you find my answer helpful, remember to accept it with the tick on the left.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If `data` is an array object, you should try with:

```
if (data.length < 99)
```

Also you can simplify your syntax:

```
$('#something').toggle(data.length < 99);
```